# If I made a double slit using microwave oven door, do I get an interference pattern?

Tags: interference, double-slit-experiment, microwaves

Imagine the following setup:

A microwave oven door with 2 holes big enough for the wavelength of microwave to pass through, high power magnetron as the source of microwave and wall of metal to produce spark when hit by the microwave. Will I get interference pattern by counting the sparks on the metal or the slit is too big for refraction?

Comment: A safer way/ [MIT Physics Demo -- Microwave Interference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kO2yFC7_k2s)

Comment: yes, you will but your oven is ~800W RF and no idea how much of that will go in to your eyes and other organs; so I would not be playing with it as a home project.